# R ggplot2: Plot geom_point with black and white without using shape?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot in black and white with ggplot2 however I don't want to use shape (ie solid black vs open black outline) because I need the shape to describe another group.

```
library(ggplot2)
str(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg, col=factor (vs), shape= factor (cyl) ))
p + geom_point(size=10) +

theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), legend.key = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=17),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=17),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=20),
        axis.title.y     = element_text(size=20), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.text      =element_text(size=22)
  ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

The plot looks like this. 
[image]

I would like to have 0 and 1 be plotted as black and white (black outline) however in this case its difficult since the shape has already been taken with factor (vs).  Is there any other thing I can do?  thanks.

Comment: You could still use color, but make 0 light grey and 1 black, and it would still print / display fairly well in B&W

Comment: @bouncyball thanks; I think I will have to plot it this way if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want two separate legends for the two factors as you have in your example, you can use "fillable" shapes and the `fill` aesthetic instead of the `color` aesthetic.  Shapes are shown [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/); the fillable ones are the ones in yellow, 21-25.

To get your legends to look how you want them, particularly the `fill` legend, you can override the shape via `override.aes` in `guide_legend`.  Here I also fill the `shape` legend in black, but that isn't necessary if you don't mind the white legend.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg, fill = factor(vs), shape = factor (cyl) 
)) + 
     geom_point(size=10) +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white")) +
     scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24, 22) ) +
     guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21) ),
            shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black" ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! that works perfectly. I especially like the extra legend guide, would not have worked without. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
str(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg, shape=paste0(vs,cyl) ))
p + geom_point(size=10) +

    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), legend.key = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size=17),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=17),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=20),
          axis.title.y     = element_text(size=20), 
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          legend.text      =element_text(size=22)
    )+scale_shape_manual(values = c("04"=15,"06"=16,"08"=17,"14"=0,"16"=1,"18"=2))
```